# Create a maximo Endpoint for an external SOAP Webservice with basic authorization

Tags: endpoint, maximo

So I have a wsdl file and based on that I want to create an endpoint in Maximo. In SoapUi it works without issues but in maximo ( from what I can see ) it doesn't do the login because the response I get is an HTML page with a login page from the other application. This thing happen also when I've written the wrong password in the SoapUI but after I've modified it everything was ok. So..if I need to use Authorization Basic and I choose HTTP handler..beside password(64 encoded),username, url, method do I need to fill something else? I've tried everything I can think about without success

Comment: Log into maximo normally and open developer tools.  go to the application tab in developer tools and look at the cookies.  if you have a LtpaToken2 you will need to implement form validation to get a token.  Had this problem previously and had to learn how to get this to work.  https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html#_form_authentication

Comment: @Milton, I've checked with developer tool and it seems I have a Ltpa Token2. I'm trying to understand how to configure the endpoint based on the link you've attached but I don't really understand. Can you please give me an example or more details?

Comment: This is a early python version of the login I found.  We have this built into an integration tool that simplifies all this so I have forgotten how it works.
def login_to_maximo():
    params = {
        "j_username": "%%USER%%",
        "j_password": "%%PASS%%",
    }
    url = "%%MAXRUL%%%%PORT%%/maximo/j_security_check"
    resp = requests.post(url, params=params)
    cookie = resp.request._cookies._cookies["%%BOXID%%"]["/"]["LtpaToken2"]
    return cookie.name + "=" + cookie.value